# ASP.NET Core MVC Identity features not working when published to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Good morning everyone.
I have published a project on IIS which works perfectly in development.

After publishing I can't log in. It does not give me any errors because I can correctly create a user but when I try to login the page reloads with the following URL
https: // localhost: 5001 / Identity / Account / Login? ReturnUrl =% 2FReservation% 2FError
without giving others errors. I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Please check your code is there any Reservation Error in it.

Comment: Check the database, whether the new user is created in the database, and whether the user account is confirmed or not (because, in asp.net core identity, it might need to confirm the account first, then enable the account. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8r6f.png))? If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.